# Como mostrar los campos vacios en vez de null en una tabla

Tags: javascript, java, sql, jsp

[image: Quiero que se muestre los campos vacios en vez de null]

Este es parte del codigo donde llamo los datos de mi clase Entidad VistaProfesional, realizaddos por una consulta en mi packete DAO donde hago un select a la tabla vista con todo esos datos.
espero sus aportes gracias.

```
<tbody>
                    <% for(VistaProfesionalBE v:listan){%>
                      <tr ALIGN=center>
                        <td><%=v.getNombre_profesional()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getApellidos_profesional()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getDescrip_TipoDocIdentidad()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getDocidentidad_profesional()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getDescip_Pais()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getDescrip_Estudios()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getDescrip_EntidadEducativa()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getDescrip_EstadoEstudios()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getDescrip_Grado()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getFecInicio()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getFecFin()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getFecExpedGrado()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getNombre_Titulo()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getDescrip_Colegio()%></td>  
                        <td><%=v.getNumColegiatura()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getFecIngColegiatura()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getDescrip_Especializacion()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getDescrip_TipoCapacitacion()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getFec_Inicio()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getFec_Fin()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getHorasLectivas()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getNombreCapacitacion()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getDescrip_EntidadCapacitadora()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getCondicion_Asistencia()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getEstado_Profesional()%></td>
                        <td><%=v.getDescrip_EstadoLaboral()%></td>
                      </tr>
                      <%} %>
                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa un operador ternario en cada `<td></td>`

Por ejemplo:

```
<td><%= ( v.getNombre_profesional() != null ? v.getNombre_profesional(), "")%></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer directamente en la directiva <% de JSP de la siguiente manera:

```
<% if(v.getApellidos_profesional() != null) {%>      
    <%=v.getApellidos_profesional()%> 
<%       
}%>
```

Para cada 1 de ellos.

En caso de que estés enviando etiquetas html del tipo *td* desde la parte Java, tendrás que controlarlo allí y setear "" en vez de null antes de que se renderice la página JSP.